# error para entrar en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

me aparece el siguiente error, despues de cambiar mi contraseña al no saber cual era, ya que queria experimentar con un formulario sencillo para despues aplicarlos en mi portafolio[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya revisaste el config.inc.php?

Comment: no puedo entrar al phpmyadmin, directamente me aparece ese error. creo que la contraseña que escibí desde el shell de XAMPP bloqueó el acceso de phpmyadmin al root, entonces, ahora estoy entre intentar modificar el root (no se como hacerlo) o desinstalar todo de nuevo

Comment: No tienes que desinstalar/instalar todo de nuevo. Conviene entender que PHPMyAdmin no es otra cosa que una interfaz gráfica para interactuar con la base de datos, la cual existe como un programa que es totalmente independiente de PHPMyAdmin. Si te está rechazando la conexión puedes conectar a la base de datos por consola y modificar las credenciales o bien editar el archivo de configuración como te indica el mensaje de error.

Comment: Por eso, si cambiaste la contraseña por consola, quizas en el config.inc.php tenías configurada entrada directa con contraseña.... Debes actualizarla en ese archivo también